# Is there a way to package chrome apps using nodejs-webkit

Tags: node.js, webkit, google-chrome-app, node-webkit

Lets say i have an app and i want it to be executable standalone. I've found that you can do that with normal webpages, webapps, using https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit.

But if its chrome packaged app how do you do that.

I know it's possible as you can see in slides it uses webkit.

https://speakerdeck.com/u/zcbenz/p/node-webkit-app-runtime-based-on-chromium-and-node-dot-js

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is possible but you will have to implement by hand all of the chrome apis you use in your chrome app

Comment: there are only 30 apis...gotta do only once right...i'd but i can't