# can we create a chrome extension for electron app with our existing codebase easily

Tags: google-chrome-extension, electron

can we create a chrome extension for electron app with our existing codebase easily?

If yes,can someone guide me how?

sorry if it's a silly question, i am new to these stuffs!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible in Electron as of v1.8.4: [BrowserWindow.addExtension()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowaddextensionpath)

Answer (score 0):

It is a silly question, as Electron runtime has nothing to do with Chrome. So you can't make a *Chrome extension* for it.

The question is a bit more curious when you ask about [nwjs](https://nwjs.io/), as it shares the JS engine with Chrome. There is some [hope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116509/is-it-possible-to-load-chrome-extension-in-node-webkit-window), but only hope. Do read that question anyway - it provides some insight.